# How to apply an existing patch to your eclipse ide

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, patch

I'm trying to get my eclipse set up on ubuntu but I've run into an incredibly annoying bug that when pressing F2 to bring up a javadoc popup all further keypresses are blocked until i click the mouse on some other ui element.

The bug itself is viewable here - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353305
and there is a patch provided here - http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/commit/?id=a7026b1b456498a95fd3935ab7b613f4c353caa4

I've found two articles about patching features in eclipse
http://aniefer.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/patching-features-with-p2.html
http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/30/patching-your-own-eclipse-ide/

I began creating a new feature patch but both of these article seem to assume that you magically will know what values to enter for "Feature ID" and "Feature version". I just have this patch linked above, I have no idea of the feature ID or version.

If someone could lay out some easy to follow steps that would be great, and maybe a bit of background I fee like there is a massive gap in knowledge here, I mean I'm really stuck as to where to look for this info.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A [feature patch](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/examples/featurePatch/org.eclipse.rcp.r422.feature/feature.xml?h=pwebster/exampleFeaturePatch) is a special kind of feature that specifies the bundles to update in an existing feature.

In my example my feature patch is updating 2 bundles in the *org.eclipse.rcp* feature.  The ID of the feature patch itself identifies the patch (so has to be unique), but is not really related to what is being patched.

What you have is a source code patch.  To create a feature patch, you would need to check out the appropriate source code for the bundle you care about (in this case SWT), apply the patch and make sure it works.  Then you can use that plus the feature patch to generate an update site (use `File>Export...>Plug-in Development>Deployable Features`) that can be used to install it into an existing system.  To get the code, here is an example of [How To Contribute](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_UI/How_to_Contribute) to Platform UI, which is similar to what you have to do for [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/git.php).

Comment: Hi Paul thanks for getting back to me,Its the end of work here now in so I'm going to try what you've suggested on monday. As an aside I realised i posted a slightly incorrect patch link, the one given in the bug report is - [link] (http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/commit/?id=a7026b1b456498a95fd3935ab7b613f4c353caa4) from which there are download links. Clicking this link downloaded a large file containing a lot of source code. at the he top level  it contained `bundles`

Comment: `bundles examples and tests` and then `org.eclipse.swt` inside bundles and then a bunch of directories including `Eclipse SWT` inside `org.eclipse.swt`. Inside I can find source for windows mac gtk. . . etc. Inside gtk i can find the modified file. I guess these are plugins but I cannot see how to import them as the plugin import wizard seems to be expecting a zip? Any thoughts?

Comment: Cheers! I'll let you know how it goes